# Filtering a list using lambda (one line code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, lambda, filter

I have a txt file with names of people.

I open it and want to get only the names with the length the user entered, using the filter and lambda  functions.

The problem is that the list I get is empty [].

```
names_file = open('names.txt').read().split()
user_choice = input("Enter name length: ")
print(list(filter(lambda c : len(c) == user_choice, names_file)))
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: `type(user_choice) == str` but `type(len(c)) == int` so they are never equal.

Comment: `input` returns a string, so if the user enters `5`, `user_choice` will be `"5"`. Equivalency between integers and strings will always be `False`.

Comment: What does the data in names_file list look like?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Thanks, that solve the problem!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: Unless you have multiple, space-separated names on each line, you can filter the file directly, without reading the entire file in to memory first. `filter(..., (name.rstrip() for name in open('names.txt')))`. Better yet, since you are immediately calling `list` on the result of `filter`, just use a list comprehension. `[name.rstrip() for name in open(...) if len(name) == user_choice - 1]`. (`rstrip` and `user_choice - 1` accounts for the trailing `\n` on each name.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user_choice = int(input("Enter name length: "))`
should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

See this line

```
user_choice = input("Enter name length: ")
```

You are taking a string input. If you want to take an integer input you need to write `int(input())`. I hope this will solve the problem.